# Safari no puede descargar este archivo pkpass / Safari cannot download passbook file .pkpass

Tags: php, json, ios, safari

Tengo un inconveniente al descargar un pase wallet en safari. Siempre me da el error de `Safari cannot download this file.`.
El archivo se descarga y se instala de manera normal en Android tal cuál se redacta en la documentación de https://walletpasses.io/developer/

Aquí dejo el `pass.json` que se genera.

```
{
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.XXXXXXXXXX",
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "organizationName": "Special Days",
  "serialNumber": "1rSDeFzU94dbOr2bcw5IM",
  "teamIdentifier": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "coupon": {
    "headerFields": [
      {
        "key": "h1",
        "label": "Fecha Cita",
        "value": "06/05/2021 08:25"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "a1",
        "label": "Concesionario",
        "value": "MAZDA GRUPO MARCOS",
        "textAlignment": "PKTextAlignmentLeft"
      }
    ],
    "backFields": [
      {
        "key": "b1",
        "label": "Nombre Cliente",
        "value": "Gean Pearre"
      },
      {
        "key": "b2",
        "label": "Concesionario",
        "value": "MAZDA GRUPO MARCOS"
      },
      {
        "key": "b3",
        "label": "Dirección",
        "value": "Carr. d Ocaña, 25 03007 (ALICANTE) ALICANTE"
      },
      {
        "key": "b4",
        "label": "Marca(s)",
        "value": "Mazda"
      },
      {
        "key": "b5",
        "label": "Teléfono del Evento",
        "value": " "
      },
      {
        "key": "b6",
        "label": "Fecha de Emisión",
        "value": "2021/06/24 02:08:04"
      },
      {
        "key": "b7",
        "label": "Fecha de Validez",
        "value": "Este pase es válido sólo el día 06/05/2021 08:25"
      },
      {
        "key": "b8",
        "label": "Condiciones",
        "value": "Sigue nuestras políticas desde el siguiente link:\nhttps://www.specialdays.es/PoliticaDePrivacidadInfoWallet/MazdaGrupoMarcos"
      },
      {
        "key": "b9",
        "label": "Actualización",
        "value": " ",
        "changeMessage": "%@"
      }
    ]
  },
  "authenticationToken": "85f6857c23751008e09e0eb006d9f08d7b2df3863c62d92c1cb1d1b688e89caf",
  "webServiceURL": "https://www.optimacrm.ai/WebHooks",
  "locations": [
    {
      "latitude": "38.5325219",
      "longitude": "-0.1781859",
      "relevantText": "Te encuentras en casa"
    }
  ],
  "barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "15302069",
    "messageEncoding": "UTF-8",
    "altText": ""
  },
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
  "foregroundColor": "rgb(0,0,0)",
  "labelColor": "rgb(0,0,0)",
  "suppressStripShine": "true",
  "description": "Pase exclusivo para los eventos de Special Days",
  "maxDistance": 500
}
```

También dejo el manifest.json

```
{
  "pass.json": "9033b2052c80903080a8155199109f34f10e39ec",
  "es.lproj/pass.strings": "06764f9188677c01410da02a813506af6fbd36de",
  "icon.png": "0b6a6c0e58a5a3142ed83cc1ca2ca26d88cf5f7f",
  "icon@2x.png": "0b6a6c0e58a5a3142ed83cc1ca2ca26d88cf5f7f",
  "logo.png": "524e54313c8b9fc6f94097d567f3d2ccb795a7e9",
  "logo@2x.png": "524e54313c8b9fc6f94097d567f3d2ccb795a7e9",
  "strip.png": "8fca81084171d927429ba5f2a06ce4b3477deb96",
  "strip@2x.png": "8fca81084171d927429ba5f2a06ce4b3477deb96"
}
```

El pkpass contiene los siguientes archivos:

```
icon.png
icon@2x.png
logo.png
logo@2x.png
manifest.json
pass.json
signature
strip.png
strip@2x.png
es.lproj
```

Comment: En la url de la pregunta todo es para Android, no hace referencia nada para iOS. Quieres que tu pase se instale en el Wallet del iPhone?

Comment: Sí, exactamente.
Todo lo referente a Android funciona perfecto, sin embargo, con respecto a iOS solo me da un mensaje de error que Safari no puede descargar mi archivo pkpass

Comment: Según Apple *...para que Wallet reconozca los pases, deben ser obligatoriamente firmados con certificados de Apple y asociados a una cuenta de desarrollador...* https://developer.apple.com/wallet/get-started/

Comment: Sí, de hecho, eso es lo que hace internamente..
Se asigna el CERIFICATE_P12, CERIFICATE_PEM y CERIFICATE_PASS (archivo .p12, archivo .pem y clave del certificado) respectivamente para luego firmar el pase con esos datos.

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar toda la información relevante en la pregunta porque si te fijas no mencionas nada sobre los certificados que hayas agregado y no mencionas si tienes una url o si en Safari con el inspector web te muestra el error del pass que no funciona. De esta manera puedes obtener una respuesta adecuada y pronta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré mi problema: varios de los valores estaban en el formato incorrecto:

- `latitude` es un tipo float (en lugar de string)
- `longitude` es un tipo float (en lugar de string)
- `suppressStripShine` debe ser de tipo booleano (y no string)